# How can I use constructor of one class as a parameter to an object in another class in Java?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

I have a class `Point` which has constructors `Point()` and `Point(x,y)`. I want to use this `Point` as a parameter in a `Circle` class, e.g.,

```
Point p= new Point(x,y);
Circle c= new Circle(p);
```

But I am getting error.

Comment: what is the error? can you print the stacktrace?

Comment: Can you post some code as well? like your constructor for the Circle class plz

Comment: please share the definitions of the classes

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: Does your Circle class have a Circle(Point) constructor?

Comment: Does the `Point` class do anything with the parameters in it's constructor? What is the type of those parameters? You need to add some details. Otherwise this question remains unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two classes, ClassA and ClassB, you can use one class object in another's constructor like this:

```
public class ClassA {
    int x;
    int y;
    public ClassA() {}
    public ClassA(int _x, int _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    ClassA classA;
    public ClassB(){}
    public ClassB(ClassA _classA) {
        classA = _classA;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA(1, 1);
        ClassB b = new ClassB(a);

        System.out.println("x: " + b.classA.x + ", y: " + b.classA.y);
    }
}
```

In your case ClassA is Point and ClassB is Circle...